# How can i combine two annotation into one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, swagger

I want to combine two annotations for summarization

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{4}+-[0-9]{3}+-[0-9]{7}+-[0-9]$", message = "must match ****-***-*******-*")
@Schema(example = "3021-700-12345567-1")
```

Schema annotation is one of the swagger anno

and this is my new annotation

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{4}+-[0-9]{3}+-[0-9]{7}+-[0-9]$", message = "must match ****-***-*******-*")
@Schema(example = "3021-700-12345567-1")
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface NewAnno {
}
```

Its work:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{4}+-[0-9]{3}+-[0-9]{7}+-[0-9]$", message = "must match ****-***-*******-*")
@Schema(example = "3021-700-12345567-1")
private String depositNumber;
```

But its not:

```
@NewAnno
private String depositNumber;
```

Comment: Are you sure Swagger supports meta-annotations like that? Can you link to the documentation that explains it?

Comment: The Spring Framework supports meta-annotations, but this is not a feature that works in general for annotations in Java.

Comment: @jorn
I didn't understand what you meant by 'meta annotation.' If you're asking whether a schema annotation can be placed above other annotations, then yes, it can.

Comment: @parsafaraji okay, but does Swagger support that? It needs to have explicit support for such a feature, it's not automatic. And I don't see any documentation that indicates Swagger does that.

Comment: There are some discussions in the Swagger Core repo ([one](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/4340#issuecomment-1571847731), [two](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3926)) that suggest that meta-annotations should work, but I haven't tried myself.